# Cannot select Bluetooth device from Sound Output

Tags: audio, bluetooth

On OSX Sierra, I can no longer select a Bluetooth Audio device for sound output. I can see the Bluetooth head set is connected and I can select momentarily under Sound Output (see attached screenshot). However, within a few seconds, the Bluetooth device de-selects itself and reverts back to Internal Speakers.

A few notes:

- I have tried a few different Bluetooth headsets and none pair with my Mac. They pair with my iPhone and other Macs so I can rule out an issue with the headphones
- I have tried deleting Bluetooth plists and re-pairing. That did not work.
- I have tried deleting plists related to audio with no luck
- yes, I've rebooted my computer.

This strikes me as an issue with core audio but I'm not sure how to address this without re-installing the entire OS

[image: soundoutputscreen]

Comment: are you sure that the headset doesn't connect to your iPhone instead? I had this problem with one and I had to disable blutooth on my iPhone when I wanted to use it with my Mac, otherwise it would always prefer to connect to the iPhone...

Comment: Yeah, positive. The bluetooth headset does connect to osx but it loses the connection soon after

Comment: This is crazy. I have a brand new Yamaha Bluetooth receiver - paiurs perfectly with the iPhone, iPad ... but High Sierra reports that it cannot be used for audio output. Looks to be connected, but iTunes takes a while to try and then fails. Anyone having any good luck?

Comment: @perkiset this was a nightmare to fix. There was something out of sync between high sierra, the blue tooth driver, and audio driver. I tried re-installing with no luck. I  ended up re-formatting my comp.

Comment: Did anyone found a solution to this?

Comment: I have also this problem with my WH-1000XM2 with my Mac Book Pro. I have to disconnect device from "Bluetooth Preferences", then reconnect: it is now selected as the right sound output.

Comment: I also have this problem with WH-1000XM3 MacBook Pro (10.14.2). Rebooting and re-pairing fixes it temporarily but it is basically make the headphones unusable with the laptop (they work fine with other devices). Would love it their is a solution

Comment: Ran into this today with WH-1000XM3 after they worked fine for weeks. So far a bluetooth (forget and) re-pair seems to have fixed it for me.

Answer (score 26):

I will add the answer.

Looking through discussions.apple.com, as usual, yields bad advice: reset, reformat, disk cleanup. Essentially do a bunch of random nonsense until the problem sorts itself out.

Before you do anything overly-complex or even irreversible. I recommend you try what I call *the monkey's gambit*:

1. Unpair
2. Forget Device
3. Pair
4. Repeat steps 1, 2, 3 *a lot*

(Look through comments for specific instructions)

Even when it seems like it's doing nothing, keep doing it. It took me 4 or 5 tries. I was nearly convinced it was the hardware, but then all of a sudden I'm back to listening to mediocre music on a pretty good bluetooth speaker.

This might have been expedited if I rebooted my computer, but I **really** didn't feel like doing that.

**TL;DR please do not reformat or reset your computer without running the monkey's gambit for a while; it might save you a more major headache.**

To be fair, this worked for me, but it is entirely possible your system is in a state where this will not help it. I do feel compelled, however, to claim that if you can see the device connected in the bluetooth menulet then it is probably not a hardware problem.

Comment: I wish I could upvote once for the answer and once for the writing style :)

Comment: Repeating steps 1, 2, 3 indeed helps Big Sur 11.0.1.  I notice also that the bluetooth device selector (visible as a radiant mountain icon in the upper right hand corner of Music) seems to a) briefly show a pop up menu that immediately disappears b) disallowing selection and c) corrupts the bluetooth connection for my audio device.  Thus, requiring steps 1,2,3 again.  I also see this icon in IOS and it works okay there.

Comment: This still works in the latest version of Monterey 12.1. It didn't wanted to see the output until I repeated the *monkey's gambit* lol

Comment: This was genius! worked for me, without needing to restart the system.

Comment: oh boy how I loathe that this may be my most useful answer on this website...

Comment: I can't believe this worked. An exemplar of superior Apple products.

Comment: Good answer. For me just disconnect and connect again via bluetooth mostly works. If that doesn't work after 1/3 times, I try the "forget device". And after that, a reboot mostly suffice.

Comment: This might help only a few of us, but let me add that the above steps didn't work in my case. I had a software called Boom 3D, installed, which produces these symptoms. After uninstalling Boom, I was able to connect to the external speaker.

Answer (score 8):

I'm using RHA 650MA headphones and they just stopped working with my macbook. Their name was visible in the bluetooth dropdown, but whenever I clicked connect, it would connect and then disconnect after a few seconds. The headphones never appeared in system `preferences -> sound`.

**Here's the solution:**

- Go to `Activity Monitor`.
- Search for `bluetooth`
- You should see the following two items:

  1. `bluetoothd`
  2. `bluetoothaudiod` (this might not show up)
- Choose each one and Click `X` icon to restart it.

Now you should be able to connect!

Comment: No entries pop up for me ..

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this by quitting launchd from Activity Monitor (Restarting)

Comment: This restarts the computer, not just the process.  Ouch.  And, it didn't work.

Comment: I am wondering, whether quitting launchd via Activity Monitor really terminates the process or just performs an unload/reload. In my case it did not cause a reboot so I think it just reloads the launchd config. Actually, it is 2022 and this answer helped me to fix problem!

Answer (score 2):

I could resolve this issue finally with removing additional audio plugins in the folder /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins.

I don’t know which of the following plugins caused the problem:

- /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Components/AppleAES3Audio.component
- /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/DVCPROHDAudio.plugin
- /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/InstantOn.driver (com.rogueamoeba.instanton-agent)