# How to make Bluetooth headphones appear in Sound Output

Tags: macbook-pro, bluetooth, catalina

I have a new pair of Cowin bluetooth headphones that work just fine with my iPhone but when I connect to my Macbook running Catalina Beta they don't appear as an option to choose for Sound output/input. Is there a way to force them to appear?

Comment: I've tried all the solutions below to no avail. It must be something with Catalina. Unfortunately I dont have another Macbook not on Beta to try it with.

Answer (score 5):

If your headphones appear as Connected in your bluetooth devices but aren't in the list for Sound Ouput, I recently found that this can be resolved by:

1. Open Activity Monitor
2. Search for bluetoothd
3. Select it, click X, click Quit

It will automatically restart and add your bluetooth devices into the other panels where they should be.  It takes about 5-10 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Basic solutions:

- Try restarting your device ;
- Try disabling and enabling Bluetooth back ;
- Try [resetting your Mac Bluetooth cache](https://www.macrumors.com/how-to/reset-mac-bluetooth-module/) ;
- Check [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/364111/342697) from [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/321413/cannot-select-bluetooth-device-from-sound-output).

Hope I helped you.
Léo

Comment: In my case, I didn't have to complete all the steps in "resetting your Mac Bluetooth cache", I just needed to reset the Bluetooth module. My problem was that my headset was connecting to Bluetooth, but not appearing in the sound output options list.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a Bluetooth icon in the menu bar. Click on this and you'll get the following menu:

[image]

Click on the connect button on the left.  Then go to system preferences and open the Sound Prefs and select your Bluetooth headset.

[image]